# ¿Es la etimología de "salario" realmente relativa a la sal con que se pagaba a los soldados romanos?

Tags: etimología, historia

Hay una pregunta formulada en English Language & Usage sobre si el origen de la palabra **salario** es un mito: [Is the etymology of “salary” a myth?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448865/is-the-etymology-of-salary-a-myth).

La pregunta recoge las dudas planteadas en [esta entrada](http://kiwihellenist.blogspot.com/2017/01/salt-and-salary.html) del blog de Peter Gainsford donde se indica que no hay evidencia de que a los soldados romanos se les pagara con sal y que de ahí venga el significado de [***salario***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X1gL4YQ) que recoge el DLE:

> ```
> Del lat. salarium, de sal 'sal'.
> ```
>
> 1. m. Paga o remuneración regular.

Por lo que he podido averiguar la palabra latina **salarium** (de sal) de la que proceden las equivalentes en las lenguas romances ya significaba [remuneración regular](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salarium).

He repasado por encima los textos de Plinio pero en ellos ya parece tener el significado general de paga e incluso premio para altos cargos y no el original de pago en especie con sal.

Traslado la pregunta aquí por si hay algún buen etimólogo o historiador en la sala que pueda ofrecer una fuente original latina donde se haga referencia a este pago en sal.

Comment: Según Corominas, la palabra _salarium_ en latín no indicaba que se les pagara en sal, sino más bien "suma que se daba a los soldados para que se compraran sal". En todo caso, si quieres conocer el significado de la palabra en latín, te sugiero el sitio dedicado al respecto: [Latin.SE]. Y si quieres llegar más atrás en la etimología, casi mejor ir directamente a [Linguistics.SE].

Comment: @Charlie Gracias por el comentario. La referencia de Corominas no es muy válida porque no conocemos la fuente de esa afirmación. Estoy de acuerdo contigo en que Latin Language es el sitio más adecuado y así se lo han sugerido a la posteadora original. Parece que no quiere postear ahí. Ya le he preguntado si no le importa que lo haga yo.

Comment: Espero que haya más suerte en el foro de latín. Yo he hecho un par de preguntas allí y la gente se ha volcado con las respuestas. Por si te interesa otra opinión, aquí va lo que decía Covarrubias en 1611 sobre la palabra _salario_: Pudo serle atribuido este nombre entendiendo debajo del de sal todo lo que es vianda y sustento, porque entra en todos los manjares. Se llamó así a la paga que se daba a los soldados por esta razón, o porque "se librassen sus pagas en las rentas de las salinas".

Comment: @Charlie Gran aporte. Con eso ya se desmonta la afirmación del supuesto investigador de que el "mito" lo inventaron los ingleses en 1860.

Comment: segun he escuchado no es que se pagara con sal, si no era una parte que se daba para comprar sal, no creo que la sal en si haya sido una moneda.

Answer (score 3):

Después de preguntar (por fin) [en el sitio de latín](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7159/2646), nuestro compañero [@luchonacho](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18793/luchonacho) nos ofrece [una respuesta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/7160/2646) con diversos textos que nos pueden aclarar el origen de la palabra. Pero antes, citemos los textos ya mencionados en los comentarios de la pregunta.

Comencemos por Corominas y su *Breve diccionario etimológico* (tercera edición muy revisada de 1973):

> *Salario*, S. XV, latín *salarium* 'suma que se daba a los soldados para que se compraran sal', y luego 'sueldo'.

Mucho antes, Covarrubias decía esto en su diccionario de 1611:

> Llamose salario el estipendio que se dava a los soldados, o por esta razon [entendiendo debaxo del de sal todo lo que es vianda y sustento], o porque les librassen sus pagas en las rentas de las salinas.

Como autoridad, confío más en Corominas que en Covarrubias, sinceramente. La propia RAE reconoce que las etimologías de Covarrubias hoy día están ampliamente superadas. Sin embargo, Covarrubias cita como fuente el capítulo 7 del libro 31 de la *[Historia natural](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalis_historia)* de Plinio el Viejo, que vivió en el siglo I:

> Honoribus etiam militiaeque interponitur salariis inde dictis, magna apud antiquos et auctoritate.

Texto que forma parte del siguiente fragmento:

> Y por tanto [...] la vida civilizada sería imposible sin sal, y tan necesario es este sustento básico que su nombre se usa metafóricamente incluso para intensos placeres mentales ('sales') [...]. Tiene lugar entre los magistrados y en el servicio extranjero, del cual viene el nombre 'salarium' ('dinero en sal'); tenía gran importancia entre los hombres de la antigüedad, como se desprende del nombre 'Salariae viae', vía a través de la cual se traía, por acuerdo, la sal a los Sabinos.

Y pasamos ya a los textos citados en la respuesta del sitio de latín, textos que aquí traduciré. Comenzamos por *[Dictionary of derivations](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112112481541;view=1up;seq=185)* (1838), de Robert Sullivan:

> SALARY. De *salarium*, en latín "provisiones que se les daba a los soldados, de las cuales la *sal* era una parte necesaria".

Esto ofrece una nueva opinión sobre el origen del término. Seguimos con *[Forgotten meanings](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hn5x1e;view=1up;seq=62)* (1886), de Alfred Waites:

> SALARY. Perteneciente o relativo a la sal. Dinero dado a los soldados para sal.

Hasta aquí coincide entonces con Corominas, pero además añade lo siguiente para dar más profundidad a la explicación (me he permitido extender un poco la cita bíblica):

> La sal era algo venerado por los antiguos. Era usada en sacrificios; por eso Moisés ordenó:
>
> > "Y sazonarás con sal toda ofrenda de grano que ofrezcas, y no permitirás que falte jamás de tu ofrenda de grano la sal del convenio de tu Dios. En toda ofrenda tuya ofrecerás sal." (Levítico 2, 13.)
>
> Así, ofrecer sal a un extraño era (y sigue siendo) reconocido como símbolo de amistad en algunas naciones orientales; y derramar sal en la mesa se considera un mal augurio. El deseo de obtener los medios para comprar sal dio lugar al origen de la palabra *salarium*.

En cuanto a textos latinos únicamente disponemos de momento del de Plinio, citado por Covarrubias; pero no veo descabelladas las respectivas opciones dadas por Sullivan y Waites.

Comment: Vaya, gracias por no olvidar esta cuestión despues de meses. Echo en falta referencias al texto citado por Covarrubias de Plinio, el cual parece ser la fuente original de este ¿mito?.